# (Homebrew-installed) zsh does not to include the right path to "/.../functions" in fpath variable

Tags: shell, zsh, oh-my-zsh

MacOS User here: I followed the right instructions to set homebrew-installed zsh as my system shell, but when I start a new Terminal window, everything crashes like

```
/etc/zshrc_Apple_Terminal:43: add-zsh-hook: function definition file not found
/etc/zshrc_Apple_Terminal:178: add-zsh-hook: function definition file not found
/etc/zshrc_Apple_Terminal:251: add-zsh-hook: function definition file not found
...
```

and many other rows of error that say it cannot find the function definition. I understood then that the default `$FPATH` variable is incorrect:

```
❯ echo $FPATH | tr ':' '\n'
/opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
/usr/share/zsh/site-functions
/usr/share/zsh/5.8/functions
...
```

It clearly doesn't include `/opt/homebrew/share/zsh/5.9/functions`; but the very odd thing is that, if I launch a new instance of zsh, everything seems to work fine.

```
❯ echo $FPATH | tr ':' '\n'
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
/opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/zsh/5.9/share/zsh/functions
...
```

It almost seems that at the first launch, Terminal still executes the system-builtin zsh (which is not v5.8, but v5.8.1, so the populated directory is `/usr/share/zsh/5.8.1/functions` instead of `/usr/share/zsh/5.8/functions`).

I already tried to create a symbolic link in `/usr/share/zsh/5.8/functions` that redirects to `/usr/share/zsh/5.8.1/functions`, but I get `ln: 5.8: Operation not permitted` error (already enabled *full-access control on disk* for Terminal).

Any suggestions?

Comment: How did you change your default shell? did you do it through `chsh` ?

Comment: First, verify which shell you start in with `zsh --version`. You might need to add `ZDOTDIR` or `FPATH` to the appropriate invocation file. Look at `STARTUP/SHUTDOWN FILES` in man zsh, and note that Mac terminal starts a login shell I believe.

Comment: @tmnd91 yes, tried to change it both with chsh (`chsh -s /opt/homebrew/bin/zsh`) and verified it though Mac Settings UI.

Comment: @dan Solved! Thank you. It was a declared `FPATH=...` in my `~/.zprofile`. Not sure why it was added there, but simply commenting it out solved the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Solved! The problem was a variable `FPATH=...` declared in my `~/.zprofile`. Thanks to @dan for the hint.